# Outputting a html form with cgi

Tags: html, forms, perl, cgi

I want to output a html form when I begin my cgi program. I know I can do this by doing the following example perl script.

```
sub MakePage()
{
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title>Hello World Form</title></head><body>\n";

print "<center><big><big><big><strong>\n";
print "Hello World Form<p>\n";
print "</strong></big></big></big>\n";

print "<FORM ACTION=\"./stdin.cgi\" METHOD=\"POST\">\n";
print "The Field...<br>\n";
print "<input type=\"text\" name=\"TXhelloField\" size=\"100\" \n";
print "value=\"" . MakeString() . "\">\n";
print "<INPUT type=\"submit\" name=\"BXsub\" value=\"Submit\">\n";
print "</form>"; 

print "</body></html>\n"; 
}

MakePage();
```

However, I want to place the html form in a its own file called form1.html and then call it with something like this:

```
sub MakePage()
{
Location: form1.html;
}
```

I am new to cgi and perl and am having trouble figuring this out and have not had much luck finding this in tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at using [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) to get a nice API for interacting with the web server (instead of printing out raw HTTP). You can still [use CGI to run your Plack programs](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack::Handler::CGI) and it gives you the flexibility to (very) easily move to using something more efficient (like FastCGI) in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *output* the header, along with a suitable status code and explanation.

```
print "Status: 302 Found\r\n"
print "Location: http://example.com/form1.html\r\n";
print "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"; 

print "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en"><head><title>Moved</title></head><body><p>This document can be found at <a href="http://example.com/form1.html">http://example.com/form1.html</a>.</p>\r\n";
```

(NB: Location headers require absolute URIs, even if most browsers will play error recovery games).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at HTML::Template or Template::Toolkit. They will help you separate your HTML from your perl code. e.g.

```
use HTML::Template;
use CGI;
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'form1.tmpl');
# replace MAKESTRING TMPL_VAR with string returned by your function
$template->param(MAKESTRING => MakeString()); 
my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header();
print $template->output();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to do a redirect, I would advise using CGI.pm's [`redirect`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER) method (`print $q->redirect('http://myserver.com/form1.html')`) rather than printing the HTTP headers manually.

If you need to put any Perl data into the returned page, add headers/footers/sidebars to the page, etc., then using a proper templating solution, as imran suggested, is definitely the way to go.  (Which one?  [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/module/Template) has been the most popular and widely-used template engine for several years, but has a reputation for being slow.  Other good options would be [Template::Alloy](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aAlloy), which is a mostly-drop-in replacement for TT which is much faster, or [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aXslate), which is what I'm personally using when I have the option.)